# Display Object as arranged in array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting

I have an object student which has variables like student->name , student->age , student->marks , student->id

I have tried this :
i have done this to get sorted array of ids

```
foreach($student as $s){
array_push($student_id_array,$s->id) }
sort($student_id_array);
```

So i have the array of sorted id of student,
but how can i display 100 instances of $student in the same order a $student_id_array ?

Comment: Remove the qoutes of the `$student_id_array`.. Now its a string and not an array.

Comment: cool , thanks @Sven , but getting the sorted array of student id is not the problem

Comment: I know, but it was something to mention ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will sorts all your `$students` array based on each `$student->id`:

```
$stud = array (
                (object)array('name' => 'John Doe', 'id' => 1),
                (object)array('name' => 'Jane Doe', 'id' => 3),
                (object)array('name' => 'Luke Will', 'id' => 4),
                (object)array('name' => 'Eric Sting', 'id' => 2)
            );
$Students = array();
foreach($stud as $s){
     $Students[$s->id] = $s;
}
ksort($Students);

foreach($Students as $s){
     echo $s->name; 
}
```

Comment: how does this any way take into consideration my sorted student id ?

Comment: Why don't you sort all `$students` array ? Remade answer .. try it

Comment: umm i like this (array) thing , ill try it and get back

Comment: @MihaiLorga can i convert the $newArray to an object after ksort($newArray) ?

Comment: Why do you need to convert to object ? Remove the `(array)` in front of `$s`.

Comment: umm , the Ksort would return me an array isnt it ? i dont want an array i want an object

Comment: Yes, you can convert it with `(object)`

Comment: @mihaiLorga , i tried your method , but i cannt convert the sorted array back to object , i tried doing $students = (object)$newArray , after sorting ie Ksort($newArray) any thoughts ?

Comment: If your class is called `Student` then you can cast it like this: `$new_student_object = (Student)$s` then use `$new_student_object` to access the object properties.

Comment: @Sven that dint work , should i use something like get instance of , or something similar ?

Comment: @user1537158 what's wrong with the code above? What doesn't work ?

Comment: @MihaiIorga , to talk to the point , right now , im already printing the list of student in my view , so if i do (object)$newArray it will be converted to std classObject and i will have to access it the way you have written , but i want to keep my view as it is , i want to convert the $newArray to same Student class object as Sven suggested , but that doesnt seem to work either

Comment: @MihaiIorga what i want is (right now) $students->array->sort()->$student(same format as before) , code you wrote is $student->array->sort()->$student(but in std class Object, this is a pain)

Comment: umm ur not getting my point , the main villain is std class object and accessing variables like this : echo $Students[1]->student->name;

Comment: But I've just did what. How do you want to display ? I don't get it ... really

Comment: foreach($student as $s){ echo $s->name }

Comment: hang on , let me check this one

Answer (score 1):

You can display the array in order (the order you created the array) by looping through it like this:

```
foreach($student_id_array as $student) {
    echo 'student #' . $student->id . ', name: ' . $student->name . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: umm let me try this , will get back in some time